# Standard or Top Text on Applied Graph Theory

Tags: algorithms, graphs, reference-request, education, books

I am looking for a reference text on applied graph theory and graph algorithms.  Is there a standard text used in most computer science programs?  If not, what are the most respected texts in the field? I have Cormen et al.

Comment: In what applications are you interested? Algorithmic applications?

Comment: I am interested in directed graphs, but want a definitive text, if such a thing exists.  I thought (hoped) that there might be a dedicated text that covered theory, history, and applications.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Searching Amazon for "applied graph theory" yields numerous results. I suggest you start there (or a similar search elsewhere), go to your library and look into the most promising candidates. Buy the one you find most accessible resp. fitting your needs. Not every book helps everybody, that's a very person-specific matter.

Comment: I searched Amazon before asking here. I though that would be obvious. Thus, I came here to see if there was a definitive text for the topic that is widely used in CS programs (see my original question).

Comment: In my experience, a "definitive text" hardly ever exists, and more so in computer science (a young field). Different books cater to different audiences and different preferences both in terms of content selection and presentation.

Comment: Yes, it appears that there is not definitive text. However, the responses thus far have turned up a few suggestions that have proven to be quite useful.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For digraphs in particular, there's Band-Jensen & Gutin's ["Digraphs: Theory, Algorithms and Applications"](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/books/dbook/). It covers quite a bit of material.

The first edition is free to download now that the second edition is out (There's a link to the pdf on their page). Of course if you've got access to a Springerlink account, you can get the second edition instead!

Apart from being free, while I'm not sure of its popularity (especially considering it's "relatively" young), it's a weighty tome, with extensive coverage from basics to quite advanced topics and from both practical and theoretical perspectives.

The other advantage is that it's one of the few (perhaps only?) full coverage texts specifically on digraphs, rather than a being a general graph theory book with material on digraphs.

Comment: Thanks! Free is always very good.  Looks like it covers my main interest (directed graphs) quite well!

Comment: In light of [an ongoing discussion on Meta](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/487), I'd encourage you to try to improve this answer by providing evidence that this text, in particular, is your recommendation. What evidence do you have to suggest that it is popular, or widely used? What evidence do you have that it is respected? Note that there is no policy, yet, on "list questions", but I am personally (not officially) curious to see how much justification people can provide.

Comment: Luke, I have done a limited review of the book you suggested and it is the best book on directed graphs that I have seen.  At 700+ pages it is quite hefty. Just reading the intro and looking at the topics I can tell this is what I have been looking for-- and, its free!! At my stage of learning, this is sufficiently definitive for my needs. It will take me a year to get through this.  Thanks for a great suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

I would take a look at the free book by Bondy and Murty: [Graph Theory with Applications](http://book.huihoo.com/pdf/graph-theory-With-applications/). This book is less-algorithmic and more graph-theoretical than other resources recommended here. There is also [a newer version of the book](http://www.springer.com/new+&+forthcoming+titles+%28default%29/book/978-1-84628-969-9), which is not available for free on the net, but is extremely well-written and with updated notation. In comparison to other free books on graph theory (as for example [Diestel](http://diestel-graph-theory.com/)), Bondy/Murty uses a less formal approach to prove and explain the theory.

The reason I have used it, is because it is the primary text-book in the course on Graph Theory at The Technical University of Denmark, lectured by [Carsten Thomassen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carsten_Thomassen), in which I have been assistant teacher for 2 years.

Comment: Wow, another free text that looks pretty good! Thanks for this great suggestion!

Comment: In light of [an ongoing discussion on Meta](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/487), I'd encourage you to try to improve this answer by providing evidence that this text, in particular, is your recommendation. What evidence do you have to suggest that it is popular, or widely used? What evidence do you have that it is respected? Note that there is no policy, yet, on "list questions", but I am personally (not officially) curious to see how much justification people can provide.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some justification.

Answer (score 3):

There is always the free [Algorithmic Graph Theory](http://code.google.com/p/graphbook/) which covers graph algorithms, data structures, traversals, and several other topics. If it doesn't have what you're looking for, at least you're not out anything.

Comment: Thanks, I have never heard of this before.  I'll add it to my library.  It appears there is no one, definitive text that is widely used, so this may be a good find.

Comment: Many thanks, for this pointer. I wasn't aware of this book. It looks very nice and has lot of exercises! And it is free!

Comment: In light of [an ongoing discussion on Meta](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/487), I'd encourage you to try to improve this answer by providing evidence that this text, in particular, is your recommendation. What evidence do you have to suggest that it is popular, or widely used? What evidence do you have that it is respected? Note that there is no policy, yet, on "list questions", but I am personally (not officially) curious to see how much justification people can provide.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at (the non free) Algorithmic Graph Theory by Alan Gibbons.  It's an oldie but quite widely used in CS, it has a computational approach but does also cover the theory.  At around 250 pages it's not too intimidating and is well respected.

Comment: In light of [an ongoing discussion on Meta](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/487), I'd encourage you to try to improve this answer by providing evidence that this text, in particular, is your recommendation. What evidence do you have to suggest that it is popular, or widely used? What evidence do you have that it is respected? Note that there is no policy, yet, on "list questions", but I am personally (not officially) curious to see how much justification people can provide.

Answer (score 2):

There is the book "Managing and Mining Graph Data" from Charu C. Aggarwal.

It contains (among others):

- Graph Mining: Laws and Generators
- Graph Data Management and Mining
- Graph Indexing
- Graph Reachability Queries
- Graph Matching
- Graph Classification

As the title suggests it concentrates on graph data and algorithms for this type of data. I don't know if this is what you are searching for, but I can really recommend this book:

[Managing and Mining Graph Data](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Managing_and_Mining_Graph_Data.html?id=Ox39uLyYh-wC&redir_esc=y)

EDIT:
Since one comment asked for "evidence" for the relevance of my answer, I would like to point out the following:

- Charu Aggarwal is one of the guiding lights in the field of Data Mining ([Top 20 Authors](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=2&topDomainID=2&subDomainID=7&last=0&start=1&end=100)).
- The book is very well written and easy to understand, even with little previous knowledge.
- There is a [review](http://www.springer.com/computer/database+management+&+information+retrieval/book/978-1-4419-6044-3?detailsPage=reviews) of this book from the [ACM](http://www.acm.org/) stating a recommodation of reading it.
- And finally: I like it :D

Comment: In light of [an ongoing discussion on Meta](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/487), I'd encourage you to try to improve this answer by providing evidence that this text, in particular, is your recommendation. What evidence do you have to suggest that it is popular, or widely used? What evidence do you have that it is respected? Note that there is no policy, yet, on "list questions", but I am personally (not officially) curious to see how much justification people can provide.

Comment: I hope I could clarify, why I think this book is relevant.